# R package development: run_examples Error: Can't find directory

Tags: r, devtools

I'm working on an R package, `pk`, say.  I've figured out how to install it using `R CMD INSTALL`, and I'm also able to check it and use it.  Now I want to use the `run_examples` function in the `devtools` package to focus on fixing up my examples.  But this is what happens:

```
> require(pk)
> run_examples(pkg = "pk")
Error: Can't find directory pk
```

Digging into `run_examples`, it seems to be crashing on the very first line, leading me to find

```
> is.package("pk")
[1] FALSE
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pkg` parameter needs to be a (full or relative) path to your package code (where `DESCRIPTION` is located), not only the package name. The default parameter `"."` works if the current directory is the package directory. Try:

```
is.package("/path/to/your/pk")
```